# Cannot flag comment in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, comment-flags

I had come across a rude comment while perusing the feed. "How wude!" I thought to myself, and tapped the comment to flag it.

To my surprise, my only options were to either visit the user's profile or vote up the comment.

While I understand that comments are not as important as questions and answers, I'd argue that it's still worth it to flag particularly bad comments. The app is great to use when following a question in live-time (beats hitting F5), so if some moderation can be taken care of quicker, I'm for it.

---

Versions:

- Stack Exchange: *1.0.6*
- Android: *4.3*
- Phone: *HTC One*

Comment: To head off any questions about my thoughts: no, I am not Jar Jar Binks.

Comment: (beats hitting F5)? mmm, do you have F5 in your HTC Once? or you mean in desktop version? because last time I checked I get live feed if the question is updated or new answers added... right?

Comment: I meant using F5 on the desktop version. And sure, it has its live feed, but it doesn't seem as satisfying as pulling up to refresh the page.

Comment: Can you link to a comment where the option isn't showing up for you? I think this is a server-side bug from the API saying you aren't allowed to flag the comment.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - Actually, your comment is an example of this issue occurring ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219692/cannot-flag-comment-in-android-app#comment711462_219692 )

Comment: Actually...that's interesting. I can't flag comments on the mobile site either. Do they draw from the same method?

Comment: @ChrisForrence try now? You might have to pull to refresh to refresh the question if it's still open on your device.

Comment: And now the flag option appears, @KasraRahjerdi! If you'd like to answer, I'll accept it within a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great catch! This was due to a bug in our newly implemented API changes to not show flag options in situations where you can't flag a question/answer/comment. It's been fixed server side so it won't require an app update to see.